# Can't print out confidence score using ultralytics and YOLO

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, yolo

I'm using ultralytics and YOLO to create a program designed to identify ID cards as seen in this article: https://medium.com/@bentanweihao/training-a-custom-object-detector-in-half-a-day-with-yolov8-5e1475fe201e

I have trained a model, and I call it in using this line:

```
model = YOLO("best.pt")
```

I then create a result using:

```
result = model(cv2.imread('CA49_01.jpg'))
```

Printing out the result yields the following:

```
[ultralytics.yolo.engine.results.Results object with attributes:
 
 boxes: ultralytics.yolo.engine.results.Boxes object
 keypoints: None
 keys: ['boxes']
 masks: None
 names: {0: 'ID Card'}
 orig_img: array([[[ 39,  82, 163],
         [ 41,  84, 165],
         [ 42,  85, 166],
         ...,
         [ 47, 109, 211],
         [ 45, 109, 211],
         [ 45, 109, 211]],
 
        [[ 40,  83, 164],
         [ 40,  83, 164],
         [ 41,  84, 165],
         ...,
         [ 47, 109, 211],
         [ 47, 109, 211],
         [ 45, 109, 211]],
 
        [[ 40,  83, 164],
         [ 40,  83, 164],
         [ 40,  83, 164],
         ...,
         [ 47, 109, 211],
         [ 47, 109, 211],
         [ 47, 109, 211]],
 
        ...,
 
        [[126, 193, 255],
         [128, 195, 255],
         [132, 199, 255],
         ...,
         [ 48, 236, 254],
         [ 50, 236, 254],
         [ 52, 236, 254]],
 
        [[132, 199, 255],
         [132, 199, 255],
         [133, 200, 255],
         ...,
         [ 48, 236, 254],
         [ 50, 236, 254],
         [ 50, 236, 254]],
 
        [[134, 199, 254],
         [133, 198, 253],
         [129, 197, 250],
         ...,
         [ 48, 236, 254],
         [ 50, 236, 254],
         [ 50, 236, 254]]], dtype=uint8)
 orig_shape: (1920, 1080)
 path: 'image0.jpg'
 probs: None
 speed: {'preprocess': 1.0228157043457031, 'inference': 12.832880020141602, 'postprocess': 2.6531219482421875}]
```

As you can see, the "probs" is "None". Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and why it isn't printing out the confidence score?

When I plot the result using :

```
res_plotted = result[0].plot()
plt.imshow(res_plotted)
```

It does actually show the confidence score in the plot, so I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the field "boxes: ultralytics.yolo.engine.results.Boxes object". You should see the confidences in the sub-field "conf" much like how the classes are in the sub-field "cls".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).